# greppling with LaTeX markup

Tags: regex, r, latex

This is both a regular expression question, and about its implementation in R. I am using [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) to typeset some documents, and need to modify the output LaTeX using [output hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks). In order to do this, I need to find some patterns in LaTeX using regular expressions.

One such pattern is `\end{figure}`. Using the [`regexpr`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) function, I am trying to match this pattern, but my attempts have been unsuccessful so far:

```
  regexpr('\\end{figure}', 'this is a multiline text 
          some more test here 
          before we get to the good stuff 
          \\end{figure}', perl = TRUE)
```

How can I match this pattern?

Comment: Or use `\\\\end{figure}`. Escapes have to be escaped in regex for them to count as a literal character. `fixed = T` does the same, but you lose some flexibility in the kind of matching patterns you can use.

Comment: @Ramnath Would you be willing to take a shot at [my question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224773/custom-chunk-hooks-in-knitr)? I am trying to match and replace a pattern using custom output hooks (this being the match and replace part).

Comment: @Roland Thanks, duh. Also, see comment to Ramnath.

Comment: Aren't curley braces also needing escapement?

Comment: Yes. I think left braces need escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.  In particular it will correctly escape the backslashes and curly braces for you.

```
x <- 'this is a multiline text 
          some more test here 
          before we get to the good stuff 
          \\end{figure}'

library(rex)
re <- rex('\\end{figure}')
re_matches(x, re)
#>[1] TRUE

# you can still use the regular expressions rex constructs 
# in all the normal R regular expression functions as well.
regexpr(re, x, perl = TRUE)
#>[1] 111
#>attr(,"match.length")
#>[1] 12
#>attr(,"useBytes")
#>[1] TRUE
```